# .Net Multiple Project Debug on VS2010

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, debugging, breakpoints

Im running three projects under one C# solution and it works fine.
Project A is the main which uses B and C.
Projects B and C compile first and then A.
A added references to B and C projects.(not the dll)
I'd like to put breakpoints in Project B and C so that I can
track during its run-time.

First time breakpoints on B and C worked fine.
From the next try, all the breakpoints grayed-out.
(next try means stop the running solution and run it again. Shft+F5 -> F5)
It seems only one time right after compiling B and C 
the breakpoints work normally.

This is cumbersome and a waste of time compiling B and C repeatedly.
Can anyone tell me how to make breakpoints on B and C
always work as normal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are getting the breakpoints disabled because your other projects are not building with your main project. Make sure you  have to set all projects to build under configuration manager. Right click on the solution and select Configuration manager. There check all the projects you want to build along with the main project. Make sure you select **`Debug`** under configuration in Configuration Manager